# PythonShell Not Working on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been using PythonShell to connect one of my python scripts to my backend using nodejs, but I've been having trouble getting it to work when I uploaded my backend to elastic beanstalk. The code is as follows:

```
import { PythonShell } from "python-shell";

const controller = class textGenerationDAO {

  static apiGenerateLyrics(req, res) {

    let options = {
      pythonPath: 'python',
      scriptPath: '/var/app/current/dao/text-generation/',
      args: [req.query.songLength, req.query.artist]
    };
    
    PythonShell.run('cli.py', options, function (err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('results: %j', results);

      let response = {
        lyrics: results[0],
      }

      res.json(response);
    });

  }

}

export default controller
```

When I use postman to call a get request and run the below code, I get an nginx 502 bad gateway error and the elastic beanstalk error log gives me this:

```
PythonShellError: ImportError: No module named pathlib
    at PythonShell.parseError (/var/app/current/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:295:21)
    at terminateIfNeeded (/var/app/current/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:190:32)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:182:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
    ----- Python Traceback -----
    File "/var/app/current/dao/text-generation/cli.py", line 3, in <module>
      from pathlib import Path {
  traceback: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n' +
    '  File "/var/app/current/dao/text-generation/cli.py", line 3, in <module>\n' +
    '    from pathlib import Path\n' +
    'ImportError: No module named pathlib\n',
  executable: 'python',
  options: null,
  script: '/var/app/current/dao/text-generation/cli.py',
  args: [ '69', 'Queen' ],
  exitCode: 1
}
```

I've also tried doing get requests with a stripped down version of the code and I get a successful response, so I know my elastic beanstalk instance is properly configured:

```
const controller = class textGenerationDAO {

  static apiGenerateLyrics(req, res) {
    let response = {
      lyrics: "Testing the beanstalk",
    }
    res.json(response);
  }

}

export default controller
```

I assume the problem is that the beanstalk instance's Python version doesn't have pathlib, but I'm not sure how to install pathlib on the instance. Any advice?

Comment: What is your EB python platform  version?

Comment: version 3.7.3, I followed the tutorial found in the read-me here https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup. It should be the standard EB environment